# How can I avoid reflections in windows when using flash?

Tags: flash, lighting, reflection, bounce-flash

I'm working a party starting at 5:30 (so it will be getting dark) which is being held in their lodge. It's a big circular room with high dark wood beams, and windows around 3/4 of it. Vendors are going to be setting up in front of the windows and I need to take their pics, but how do I get a picture of them without getting the reflection in the window behind? I know I can bounce off the windows but I'm getting nervous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are a few options you could try:

1. Is flash required? Will there be enough ambient light in the room so you can get away with a wider aperture/higher ISO?
2. Use the subject to hide the reflection. When composing your shot, make sure that they are directly in line between the window and the flash, so when it goes off it won't be seen.
3. Purposefully shoot so that the reflection can be seen in the window, but make it as easy as possible just to clone out.
4. Is off camera flash an option? Position your light source at an angle so it lights the scene, but the reflection is not seen.
5. A bit more blunt than point 3 and depending on your editing skills. As it's going to be dark outside so will just be black. Don't worry. Fix in post. It's always preferable to get right on camera. But this could be an option.

This isn't an exhaustive list. I'm sure others will have plenty of other ideas.

A note though, you may want to shoot a narrower aperture, and move the subject as far back from the windows as you can, just to kill some of the ambient reflection as this will light up smears and fingerprints though.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the venue has shades they could temporarily pull down behind them (or curtains to pull closed) to help prevent a hot spot.

Otherwise, you could opt for bringing your own backdrop that can easily fit in the tight quarters behind them...

Answer (score 0):

Use an umbrella or any masking technique to evenly spread your light when using extra lighting/flash. This will improve the light distribution and unwanted glare in photographs..

[image: Use white umbrella or any other masking techniques]

Comment: How will this prevent reflections in the windows?